# Changing the type of a statement in Swift according to the value

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting a Json get request and my value is an array hence why I put my JSONSerializaion `as? NSArray`.

However, sometimes in my backend the values aren't sent as an array but a dictionary, so how can I check the type of my value and change the `as?` accordingly, if that makes any sense

```
do{
    let json = try 
    JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSArray //This is what I want to change
```

Sometimes the values are sent as a dictionary so how can I make my app know to execute `as? NSDictionary` instead of `as? NSArray`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably use a `switch` to distinguish the possibilities:

```
do {
    switch try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: arrayJson, options: .mutableContainers) {
    case let array as NSArray:
        // Use array here. For example:
        print("got an array of \(array.count) elements")

    case let dictionary as NSDictionary:
        // Use dictionary here. For example:
        print("got a dictionary with keys: \(dictionary.allKeys)")

    case let other:
        print("I got something I didn't understand: \(other)")
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

You could instead use multiple `if let` branches if you want:

```
do {
    let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: arrayJson, options: .mutableContainers)
    if let array = object as? NSArray {
        print("got an array of \(array.count) elements")
    } else if let dictionary = object as? NSDictionary {
        print("got a dictionary with keys: \(dictionary.allKeys)")
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use optional binding

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [Any] {
    // handle the array    
} else if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
    // handle the dictionary
}
```